How long do you ideally spend on reviewing a journal submission as a reviewer?
I am new to volunteering as a peer reviewer for a journal. I want to be helpful to the authors, but recognise that my time is valuable. I'm just wondering, how do you think about limits to time spent reviewing papers if you have experience doing so? Are there aspects of the paper in question you would consider? Are there considerations prior to accepting a review? Sorry if this is an open-ended question.
For reference, I work in environmental science and climate adaptation policy

It really depends on the research area and on the paper, so you may want to narrow down your question. For instance, in my area, math, it can take me between a couple of hours on one extreme and a year at the other extreme.

fair point Moishe, I work in climate and environmental policy

You should edit your question, accordingly since comments are meant to be ephemeral.

Some related questions: How much time should one spend refereeing a paper?, How much time should I spend on reviewing a paper?, How much time should you spend on reviewing a paper? How much time do academics in fact spend refereeing the research of others, on average?, When is it appropriate to decline a review request?
